# How to save images in Redis? I am using Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am using Ruby on rails as my web server. I get images uploaded as files through the website. Then I want to save it in redis (not save the address but the file itself in redis)

I can save the file as

```
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(filename.read) }
```

But when I try to save the file using the following command

```
$redis.set(filename.original_filename,filename.read)
```

I  get (nil) when I try to view it using redis-cli

```
> get "filename1"
(nil)
```

Comment: what is the `filename`?

Comment: filename is what I get from params[:uploaded_files] which are the params passed from the file_field_tag

Comment: You can't read the file from a disk with `filename.read` if `filename` is just a name of file. you should write a code to read the file like: `IO.read(filename)`, then you will be able to assign to to redis

Comment: filename is not a file on disk. Its a ruby object. "uploaded_files"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb4dbb14 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141207-28286-18ijngr>, @original_filename="ABC.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_files[]\"; filename=\"ABC.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">

Comment: is that uploaded file `filename=\"ABC.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n"`? I believe not

Comment: Yes. That is the uploaded file

Comment: that is only the name, where is the file itself?

Comment: It is an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object. The data of this is accesible by filename.read Only thing is that I am not able to save this  in redis. Is there some special function to assign datafile to a key in redis?

Comment: could you provide the `filename.class` here?